# javascript: skip a specific thrown error

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling

I have a page which includes a js-file. It's a jquery Plugin, but I think thats not important. The plugin break with a manually thrown error at one point.

```
(function($) {
    $.pkp.classes.Handler = function($element, options) {
        /* ... */

        if (this.data('handler') !== undefined) {
            throw new Error('blub');
        }
```

If I remove the line it works perfektly, so I think the check is not necessary. Unfortunatley I can not change the js-file (it would get overwritten every update), but I could savely include another one.

I tried to catch the error and let the script continue untouched as if the error throwing line where deleted.

```
$(window).error(function(e){
    var t = 'Handler.js';
    var l = t.length;
    var file =     e.originalEvent.filename.substr(e.originalEvent.filename.length - l, l);

    if ((e.originalEvent.lineno == 38) && (file == t)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return true;
    }
```

})

I tried something similar with window.onerror. The result is, that in both cases the error doesn't appear, but the script does not continue as it would, if the line was deleted.

I know it would be better to find the source of the misbehaviour but its a very complicates bunch of scripts, and everything works still perfectly after I put a newer jQuery and a migration script there - only this single line makes problems, so I thought maybe it's more efficient just to eliminate the error without understanding it completely...

Any suggestions?

Comment: a brutal way is to rewrite that specific function on your new js without touching the original one.

or you should force the data("handler") to be "undefined" before the function trigger.

Comment: That would be the best. Maybe I should focus on that. Most likely it's the jquery data function, wich reads the data attribute. If I could change that before, maybe...

Comment: The reason was that the jQueries data-function returns the object, if you give undefined as argument. I made a wrapper to the jQuery function to prevent this kind of behaviour.